# Sharing one class instance in Express application

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application where I'd like to share a singleton class - at the start of application singleton is created, user specific data is set and used throughout the application. This works well now, but I am not sure how this approach will behave when multiple users access the application. I am thinking that this is not thread safe and cause shared data to be overwritten by different processes that use it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking that this is not thread safe and cause shared data to be overwritten by different processes that use it.

That is correct.

What do you mean by "used throughout the application"?

- Data related to the user that remains even if the user logs off and logs on again later? That would require a database.
- Or data that is needed only between logon and logoff?

In the latter case you need *session handling* where data is associated with one browser session (technically a session cookie that is deleted when the browser is closed). An example is the [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) package that allows you to write all session-related data into the `req.session` object and this object will be re-used by all requests made with the same session cookie (that is, all requests the user's browser makes to your application until the browser is closed).

The `req.session` object must be serializable by JSON, however, so it cannot be a class instance. See [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#user-content-reqsession) in the package documentation.

Alternatively, if the data are needed only during one request (shared by several middleware functions), you can write them into `res.locals`. This can even hold class instances.

Comment: Thank you. my scenario is the following. I have three modules that need to access common data that is set when REST point is executed. I can pass this data from module to module via method calls, but was looking for a way to set this data in some shared object and reuse it throughout the REST call. It's basically something like router(var a) -> controller(var a) -> service(var a), I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: See my augmented answer.